# ubuntu 12.04 installation fatal error

Tags: 12.04

I am trying install ubuntu 12.04 among with win7. During hardware configuration I am receiving the following fatal error:  "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sad' failed.  Using the same installation disc in another pc the installation was completed without problems. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing from a live median such as a boot disk or are you installing from within windows then letting the computer reboot?

Also I am assuming that you meant `grub-install/dev/sda` and not `grub-install/dev/sad`

I believe your are getting this failure at the point when Stage 1 of GRUB installation is installing into the MBR which points to Stage 2 afterwards.

Post some more information about your hardware. Motherboard, cpu, age of computer, hard drives (and how did you partition it) etc....

Answer (score 0):

for me it solved by running boot-repair process from here [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

it means that you should error come and then in live ubuntu run the boot-repair command.
if your windows partition didnt come in boot page , you should run following command after rebooting ubuntu :
`sudo update-grub`

and now my problem solved.
i hope this work for you